# Usage of adverb of time (for instance daily) in past and present time sentences

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs

1. He plays this game daily.
2. He played this game daily.

According to grammatical rules, verb should be simple present tense if time of the action is not mentioned specifically if it has an adverb of time describing a regular action (**daily** in the above sentence).
My question is sentence no.2 correct? If so, can someone pleas explain why it would still be correct to use **daily** in a sentence with a simple past verb?

Comment: Could you explain further about the "grammatical rule(s)" (add a reference to it)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you learned that grammar rule, but past tense is as applicable as present tense.

With adverbs that describe the frequency of repeated actions (such as "daily," "regularly," or "often"), simple present tense means that the set of repeated actions is still happening. For example:

> We play "Dungeons & Dragons" daily.

This means you and your friends play the fantasy role-playing game "Dungeons & Dragons" every day, including today. You played yesterday and the day before, and you also have plans to play tomorrow. That's a lot of "Dungeons & Dragons"!

> We played "Dungeons & Dragons" daily.

This means you used to play "Dungeons & Dragons" every day, but you stopped playing at some point. Maybe you guys got bored and decided to play "Magic: The Gathering" instead. Or maybe you still play "Dungeons & Dragons" every once in a while, but not daily anymore.

Comment: Is my no. 2 sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought my answer clearly explains that both past or present are good. Do you not understand my answer?